# How to do Control F5 with Javascript with location.reload method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I submit delete a list data with ajax . Further I want to refresh the page . But it popped a screen like page refresh. when I call `location.reload();` method like <kbd>F5</kbd> functionality. But I want to simulate a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. How I can resolve it.

Comment: Why do you want to refresh the page if you're using AJAX? Just do the work on the DOM upon success.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `location.reload(true)`?

See the forcedReload parameter on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Answer (score 0):

I tried with `window.location.reload(true);` but it didn't work.
Then, I just reloaded the specific div of the list:

```
$('#myDiv').load(document.URL +  '#mydiv');
```

it worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solutions.